# MySQL #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list (FULLTEXT indexes set)

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8 in phpMyAdmin I'm getting:

```
#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

The FULLTEXT indexes are set on the respective columns.

The query is:

```
SELECT *
  FROM specimen
  JOIN topography_index
    ON substring(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) =
       topography_index.topography_index_code
  JOIN morphology
    ON morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code
  left JOIN specimen_image_lookup
    ON specimen_image_lookup.specimen_fk = specimen.specimen_pk
  left JOIN image
    ON image.image_pk = specimen_image_lookup.image_fk
  left JOIN specimen_audio_lookup
    ON specimen_audio_lookup.specimen_fk = specimen.specimen_pk
  left JOIN audio
    ON audio.audio_pk = specimen_audio_lookup.audio_fk
 WHERE MATCH (specimen.clinical_history,specimen.macroscopic,specimen.microscopic,specimen.conclusion) AGAINST ('$q' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) GROUP BY specimen.specimen_pk ORDER BY (specimen.room = 'f') DESC
```

The odd thing with this is that my PHP application that contains the query has no problem retrieving the records from that search with '*' as the search term. The PHP application has had no problems for years.  I only came across this when I got the same error on a properly indexed version in MySQL 8

see [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/csaVwttUL1XCFac9iboDFT/0) or this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/298510) which reports odd errors when running the query...

**UPDATE**

This is the script with that query in my PHP app which has no problem getting the records, eg. using the wildcard *

```
<?php
require_once('../connection/connect.php');
mysqli_select_db( $connection, $database );


$q = $_POST['query'];


$query = "SELECT *
  FROM specimen
  JOIN topography_index
    ON substring(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) =
       topography_index.topography_index_code
  JOIN morphology
    ON morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code
  left JOIN specimen_image_lookup
    ON specimen_image_lookup.specimen_fk = specimen.specimen_pk
  left JOIN image
    ON image.image_pk = specimen_image_lookup.image_fk
  left JOIN specimen_audio_lookup
    ON specimen_audio_lookup.specimen_fk = specimen.specimen_pk
  left JOIN audio
    ON audio.audio_pk = specimen_audio_lookup.audio_fk
 WHERE MATCH (specimen.clinical_history,specimen.macroscopic,specimen.microscopic,specimen.conclusion) AGAINST ('$q' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) GROUP BY specimen.specimen_pk ORDER BY (specimen.room = 'f') DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if($result){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

if (empty($row['image_thumbnail'])){
    $thumbnail = "<img class='specimen_record_thumbnail' data-specimen='" . $row['specimen_pk'] . "' src='images/no_thumbnail.png' border='0' />";
} else {
    $thumbnail = "<img class='specimen_record_thumbnail' data-specimen='" . $row['specimen_pk'] . "' src='specimen_media/" . $row['specimen_pk'] . "/" . $row['image_thumbnail'] . "' border='0' />";
}

if (empty($row['audio_file'])){
    $audio = "";
} else {
    $audio = "<div class='audio' data-audio='specimen_media/" . $row['specimen_pk'] . "/" . $row['audio_file'] ."'></div>";
}

if($row['room'] == 'f'){
    $class = 'top_specimen';
    $image = "<img class='t_image' attribute rel='tooltip' and title='Top 250 specimen' src='images/top.png' />";
} else {
    $class = 'specimen';
    $image = '';
}

if ($row['snop_axis'] == 'M'){
    $nomen = $row['morphology_nomen'];
    $snop_axis = 'M';
} else if ($row['snop_axis'] == 'F'){
    
    $f = $row['snop_code'];
    $query_f = "SELECT * FROM functions WHERE functions_code = '$f'";
    $result_f = mysql_query($query_f, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_f = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_f); 
    
    
    $nomen = $row_f['functions_nomen'];
    $snop_axis = 'F';
}
    
echo "<div class='specimen_record_container'>" . $thumbnail . "&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='diagnosis' title='" . str_replace("'","&#8217;",$row['conclusion']) . "' rel='tooltip'>Diagnosis</div>&nbsp;<span class='" . $class . "'> " . $row['topography_index'] . '.' . $row['snop_axis'] . $row['snop_code'] . '<sup>' . $row['example'] . "</sup></span><span class='no_cursor'>" . $image . "&nbsp;&nbsp;Room: " . strtoupper($row['room']) . "&nbsp;&nbsp;(" . strtoupper($row['position']) . ")</span></div><div class='nomen_text_small'>(T): " . $row['topography_index_nomen'] . "<br />(" . $snop_axis . "): " . $nomen . "</div>" . $audio . "<p><br /><br />" ;  
}
echo "<span class='sub_heading'>Total specimens: " . $total_rows . "</span>";
} else {
    echo 'No specimens available online';
}
?>
```

and the specimen table schema as exported from phpMyAdmin:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `specimen` (
  `specimen_pk` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `unit_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `topography_index` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `snop_axis` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `snop_code` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `example` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `gender` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `age` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NA',
  `clinical_history` text NOT NULL,
  `specimen` text NOT NULL,
  `macroscopic` text NOT NULL,
  `microscopic` text NOT NULL,
  `conclusion` text NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `room` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`specimen_pk`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext` (`topography_index`,`snop_code`,`clinical_history`,`macroscopic`,`microscopic`,`conclusion`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `specimen` (`specimen`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3279 ;
```

And a grab showing the FULLTEXT indexes for table 'specimen' in phpMyAdmin:

[image]

Comment: I will bet you 36 bitcoins that one of the following 2 statements is true: a) your php app and phpmyadmin are connected to a different database b) the queries in your php app and phpmyadmin are not actually the same. To verify that the second statement is true, you should check if the column list in `match()` is *exactly* the same (e.g. has the same columns, and all of them - the order can be different though), and that you are using "NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE" in both (and not boolean mode, which would work, and thus might be what you are doing in your php app).

Comment: Same database, same query.  You can keep your bitcoin. the db fiddle is an export of the relevant tables from phpMyAdmin.  It shows the fulltext indexed columns.  The query fails.  But my app uses the same DB and it works.  Just the query in PHPMyAdmin is failing for some reason.  I have updated my OP with the app script with that query.

Comment: and also the table 'specimen' structure...

Comment: Nevertheless, why is the error happening in phpMyAdmin - separate instances for MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8.0.  Same error same structures.

Comment: Your fulltext index does not match the query, e.g. it has 2 more columns. The columns in `match()` have to be the same (e.g. all 6). That is why you get the error about a missing index (for the 4 columns). The only exception is: MyISAM table with a boolean search - then MySQL generates a missing index on the fly (which is slow though). Which is why I assumed your queries differ. There is really no other way that the query works. Nevertheless, to make it work (and/or fast), add the correct index (or add columns to the `match()`). Why it currently works: it really really shouldn't.

Comment: As a side note: using the search term $q directly can cause all kind of (security) problems, e.g. your query should fail if you use a `'` in your search.

Comment: And another thing: `*` doesn't actually work as a wildcard in natural language mode, neither is a single `*` (with no letter before) a valid search term (you wrote that you used `"*"` as a search term, but it might have been unprecisely worded). So if you get (all) results with just `*`, it's another indication that this might not be the query in the php app. Is it possible that this is not the correct file? (Can you modify the file and e.g. create a syntax error in the sql code and see if you still get results, or change the title and check if it is has an effect?)

Comment: @Solarflare  You are correct.  The script was the right one (I modified the query to test, but could also see that in developer tools > headers etc).  Adding the missing columns to the query fixed it.  No idea why the * retrieved all records though...something for me to look into.  If you want to put this into an answer I'll mark it as correct.